# how to return jquery ajax success result

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to return jquery ajax success result

```
function name (LevelId) {
    var passobj = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetValues' + '/?LevelId=' + LevelId,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            passobj = result;
        },
        complete: function () { },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
    return passobj;
}

  returned =name(id);
```

Comment: Contrary to what @Niko and @Jim said, your code should work, considering that you correctly set `async = false`. Can you check that the JSON object returned is correct?

Comment: What doesn't work about this?

Comment: actually by using alert(returned) it shows as [object Object].
wen i try to drop down this values, the drop down was empty.
So i had a doubt in this whether the function return or not

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
ajaxCall(urls, data).success(function(data){
    // get the result
});

function ajaxCall(url, data){   
    var result;

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data
    });
}
```

Comment: please mind your code formatting in future :-)

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, because the ajax request is performed asynchronous what means that your function returns `null` - the success event handler is not called until the response from the server is retrieved (what may take some time). You will need to refactor your code using events.

```
function name(id, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: callback
    });
}

name(17, function(returned) {
    // work with the response...
});
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, didn't notice that you set `async: false` - in that case your code is actually supposed to be working fine, if I don't miss anything again.